# How do I authenticate Jenkins to run Azure xplat cli commands?

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-xplat-cli

I have a Jenkins running on Ubuntu.
I want to create jobs that will kick-off Azure xplat-cli commands.
How do I authenticate Jenkins?

Comment: The commands that I want to perform are the **ARM commands**, not Service Management if that makes any difference.

Comment: I found great article by *David Ebbo* that explains how to achive this using combination of Azure Portal (old) and Powershell Cmdlets:
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html

This gave me the insight to the process, I moved on and installed *Jenkins on Windows* so I can run Powershell on it, so this awesome article fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

We achieved the same using this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-service-principal-with-password---azure-cli

Briefly you have to create a new application record within Azure Active Directory that will have its own login and password. Then you should grant required permissions to that account. After that you can perform a fully non-interactive login command that works for ARM model.

Comment: Another helpful article based on @izzekil's article https://manesh.me/2015/10/15/options-for-azure-cli-logins-step-by-step-guidance/#_Login_with_Service

Comment: After logging in non-interactive, be sure to set the current account to the Subscription that you gave the sp permissions to.
`azure account set MY_SUB`
If you have multiple